# Is there any equation governing the spread of radial wicking of liquid on paper?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

According to Lucas-Washburn model, wicking of a liquid (of infinite reservoir) on a vertical paper or other porous medium is weakly described by the equation:

$$h^2 = \frac{4 \sigma \cos\theta}{\mu} \frac{K}{\varepsilon R} t$$

Is there any equation which describes the radial wicking such as when a drop of liquid (finite reservoir of liquid) falls on a horizontal paper, how far does it travel?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can find there is not a simple equation like the Lucas-Washburn model you give above. [This paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002197970298450X) considers the spreading of liquid drops over dry porous layers, such as a drop of water absorbing into and spreading out across a sheet of paper.

They derive a pair of coupled differential equations for the evolution of the radius of the drop base, $L$, and the radius of the wetted area of the substrate, $l$, which are

$$
\frac{dL}{dt}=0.1\left(\frac{4(V_0-\pi m\Delta l^2)}{\pi}\right)^{0.3}\left(\frac{10\gamma\omega}{\mu}\right)^{0.1}\frac{1}{(t+t_0)^{0.9}}-\frac{2\pi m\Delta K_p p_c L}{3\mu(V_0-\pi m \Delta l^2)\ln \frac{l}{L}}
$$

and

$$
\frac{dl}{dt} = \frac{K_p p_c}{\mu l \ln\frac{l}{L}},
$$

not amenable to analytic solution.

We can see from the first equation that the evolution of the drop base has two components, one acting to increase the radius and the other to decrease it. As the drop is absorbed into the substrate, the surface adjacent to the drop boundary becomes wetted and causes the drop to spread out. However, the absorption of the drop into the substrate reduces its volume and therefore its radius. This means that the drop has a maximum radius.

Numerical solution of the differential equations together with experimental data for the spreading of a drop of SO500 silicon oil onto a cellulose nitrate membrane is shown below.

[image]